# Missing brackets on equations

Tags: errors, brackets, sharelatex

I'm writing a couple of equations in LaTex (it's my first time using it) and, although I'm finding the general usage pretty straight forward I keep getting a missing brackets warning from ShareLatex that I can't fix, it doesn't tell me where it's missing just the line in which it is missing. Could anyone help me figure out where's the missing bracket in these?

Eq.1

```
\left\lfloor\frac{n}{\log_2 (n/2)}+n^\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\right\rfloor \leq \Omega(n\wr) \leq \left\lfloor\frac{n}{\log_2(n/2}+n^\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right\rfloor
```

Eq.2

```
\begin{align*}
T_{prod}F(n\wr)&\simeq\beta n\log\log(n)\sum_{1\leq i\leq \lfloor lg\hspace{2pt}n\rfloor} \log\left(\alpha n2^\left(-i\right)\right)\\
&\simeq \frac{\alpha}{\beta}n(\log n)^2 \log\log n \\
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to put some of your exponents between brackets, so that `^` is followed by `\left(`. I took the opportunity to slighly improve your formula with the `\mathclap` command from `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ \left\lfloor\frac{n}{\log_2 (n/2)}+n^{\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}\right\rfloor \leq \Omega(n\wr) \leq
\left\lfloor\frac{n}{\log_2(n/2)}+n^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right\rfloor
 \]

\begin{align*}
T_\text{prod}F(n\wr)&\simeq\beta n\log\log(n)\sum_{\mathclap{1\leq i\leq \lfloor lg\:n\rfloor}} \log\left(\alpha n2^{\left(-i\right)}\right)\\
&\simeq \frac{\alpha}{\beta}n(\log n)^2 \log\log n \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On spot @Bernard, worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for the formula improvement as well! I'll make sure to check the mathtools package in depth :)

Answer (score 0):

If you could show the output it would help figure this out, but if you are referring to the `\lfloor` and `\rfloor` braces not appearing:

you will want to put the terms appearing between them inside `{}` see this example

`\left \lfloor{\frac{x}{2}}\right \rfloor`

inserted into your equation 1:

```
  \begin{align*}
  \left \lfloor{\frac{n}{\log_2 (n/2)}+n^\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}\right\rfloor 
  \leq \Omega(n\wr) \leq 
  \left\lfloor{\frac{n}{\log_2(n/2}+n^\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right\ rfloor
  \end{align*}
```

Produces:

[image: Is this your desired output?]

Comment: Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \left 
l.52 $$\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{\log_2 (n/2)}+n^\left
                                                  (\frac{1}{6}\right)}\right...
A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
(If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.52 ...2 (n/2)}+n^\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}\right
                                                  \rfloor \leq \Omega(n\wr) ...

Comment: I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

Comment: This is another log:
<to be read again> 
                   \left 
l.62 \end{align*}
                 
A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
(If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)

Comment: I've added your braces but still didn't fix it. I have however discovered that there's something to do with the text align tags.

Comment: I don't have 50 rep yet so I can comment on the answer below but he is correct. pdflatex did yell at me about the missing `{` on the exponent but just inserted them and moved right along.